# Parsing HTML form data

Tags: html, c, cgi

When I simply print the query I get:

one=1&two=2&three=3&four=3&five=3&six=3

Still not working!!!! I am about to go nuts.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    char *data;
    float prices[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int a, b, c, d, e, f;

    printf("%s%c%c\n",
    "Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1",13,10);

    printf("<title>Bill</title>\n");
    printf("<h3 align=center >Bill</h3>\n");

    data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");

    if(data == NULL){
            printf("<p>Error!</p>");
    } else {
    printf("%s", data);
    sscanf(data, "one=%d&two=%d&three=%d&four=%d&five=%d&six=%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e,       &f);
    }

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Could you post the code where you try to parse this query?

Comment: You haven't posted the query parsing code, which is at the core of your question.  Most likely that query parsing code is causing your CGI program to crash, which is shown to the web browser as a 500 Internal Server Error.  Without the code, we can't determine why your program is crashing.

Comment: Take a look at my answer again. You're probably messing with something in your format. It could also be useful to read the sscanf documentation in that link I posted in my answer.

Comment: Also, could you post the request URL that you're using or the fields of your form?

Comment: You should put the code where you use the sscanf inside an else statement of that if above which compares if data is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to parse this string is using `sscanf`. For this example:

```
one=2&two=1
```

you could use:

```
int one, two;
sscanf(data, "one=%d&two=%d", &one, &two);
```

More information about sscanf here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/

Comment: You need to change according to your request string. For example, if you have an URL like this: "firstArg=12&secondArg=32" you need to change the format of your sscanf to "firstArg=%d&secondArg=%d". It's just like the scanf, but instead of reading from the stdin you read from your string.

Comment: Ahh ok. So the arguments I need to use are the exact names of the fields in my html form right?

Comment: Ok, I somehow still am having problems..my arguments are exactly that of my html form. Printing the query string works fine and my input is being sent to my CGI properly. Is there any other reason my sscanf could be causing this 500 error?

Comment: Post your query string and we'll try to help you.

Comment: Show us the code. in your current code you dereference invalid pointers.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an easy and not error prone way to deal with this issue?

Yes; there exist various C libraries, such as [cgic](http://www.boutell.com/cgic/) and [C CGI](http://libccgi.sourceforge.net/doc.html), that handle common CGI tasks like this one. (If neither of those is to your taste, try [Googling "C CGI library"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+cgi+library) for other options.)

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't parse anything, so how do you expect to get the values? (Like others said, the most simple way is to use `sscanf`. note that it will work only if you know the names and order of the arguments, and that you should unescape characters handly after that.)
2. Your code have some bad things, like `if (data==NULL) ... printf("%s",data)` (if `data` may be NULL, why do you print it), and using `quantities` without allocating space to it.